# How to compile SQLite ICU extension for windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, sqlite, icu

I'm using SQLite as my database in an electron app. This is the code which i use to compile ICU extension as a run-time loadable extension on Linux.

```
gcc -fPIC -shared icu.c `icu-config --ldflags` -o libSqliteIcu.so
```

This generates a `.so` file that i can load into SQLite at run-time when my electron app is running on linux. How to compile ICU extension in order to be loaded into SQLite when electron app is running on windows.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#compiling_a_loadable_extension

Comment: @Shawn would you please elaborate?. I don't think the info on the page you linked suffices. I'm running Linux right now according to the page i should run `gcc -g -shared icu.c -o libSqliteIcu.dll` on windows is that right? Or it can be done on Linux too?.Also I had to install both `libicu-dev` and  `libsqlite3-dev` on Linux to make it work.

Comment: There are examples for a couple of different windows compilers in the documentation. You'd have to include any ICU specific flags and libraries too, of course.